# Problem with jooq and spring boot with gradle

Tags: spring-boot, h2, jooq, jooq-codegen

I'am using jooq plugin with spring boot in gradle and i have a problem with h2 table.
My settings.gradle is:

```
    pluginManagement {
        plugins {
            id 'java'
            id 'war'
            id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.17'
            id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
        }
    }
```

i should use the 2.7.17 of spring boot to eliminate some cve in older spring boot library.

my build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.7.10"
        postgresqlDriverVersion = '42.4.2'
        coroutineVersion = "1.6.4"
    }
     dependencies {
        classpath 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:8.4.0'
    }
}


plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg" version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring" version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id "nu.studer.jooq" version "8.2.1"
    id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "2.0.4"
    id "idea"
    id "eclipse"
    id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.35.0"
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
    annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation 'org.jooq:jooq-meta-extensions:3.18.7'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'

    // systemd integration: notifies systemd that the application started successfully (or failed)
    implementation("com.github.jpmsilva.jsystemd:jsystemd-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1")

    // kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:${coroutineVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive:${coroutineVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:${coroutineVersion}")

    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:3.0.0")

    // Jackson Kotlin
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")

    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    implementation("javax.activation:activation:1.1")
    implementation("org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:2.7.8")

    // Cache provider
    implementation("com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.9.3")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.1.6.Final")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:6.1.6.Final")

    implementation('commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0')
    implementation("commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15")


    // Postgresql driver
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlDriverVersion}")

    //jooq
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlDriverVersion}")
    jooqGenerator("org.jooq:jooq-meta-extensions")

    // liquibase
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.1")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.1.1")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.15")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlDriverVersion}")
    liquibaseRuntime("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3")
    liquibaseRuntime("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25")
    liquibaseRuntime("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")

    //embed the webapp in the fat JAR
    runtimeOnly(project(":logs-frontend"))

    // ------- TEST -------
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.7.15")
    testImplementation("net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.2")
    testImplementation("net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.9.2")
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1"
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.3.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.3.1")

    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn 'dependencyCheckAnalyze'
}


jooq {
    // use jOOQ version defined in Spring Boot
    version = dependencyManagement.importedProperties['jooq.version']

    configurations {
        main {
            generationTool {
                generator {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator"

                    database {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase"
                        properties {
                            property {
                                key = 'scripts'
                                value = 'src/main/resources/db/changelog/main/*.sql'
                            }
                            property {
                                key = 'sort'
                                value = 'alphanumeric'
                            }
                            property {
                                key = 'defaultNameCase'
                                value = 'lower'
                            }
                        }
                        includes = '.*'
                        excludes = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS'
                    }

                    generate {
                        fluentSetters = true
                        pojos = true
                        javaTimeTypes = true
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = "fr.logs.jooq"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('generateJooq').configure {
    // make jOOQ task participate in incremental builds (which is also a prerequisite for participating in build caching)
    allInputsDeclared = true

    // make jOOQ task participate in build caching
    outputs.cacheIf { true }
}

compileKotlin.dependsOn(tasks.named('generateJooq'))


bootJar {
    dependsOn(":logs-frontend:webjar")
    archiveFileName = "testjars-${rootProject.version}.jar"
    exclude("**/application*.yaml", "**/*.jks")

    launchScript()
}

bootJarMainClassName {
    dependsOn(":logs-frontend:webjar")
}
apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'

dependencyCheck {
    failOnError=true
    failBuildOnCVSS = 1
}
```

but when try the command gradlew generateJooq i have the error below:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Precision
> ("2147483647") must be between "1" and "1000000000" inclusive; SQL
> statement: select INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.DOMAIN_SCHEMA,
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.DOMAIN_NAME,
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.TYPE_NAME,
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.PRECISION, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
> DOMAINS.SCALE, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.IS_NULLABLE,
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.COLUMN_DEFAULT,
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.CHECK_CONSTRAINT from
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS where (INF
> ORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.DOMAIN_SCHEMA in (cast(? as
> varchar(2147483647)), cast(? as varchar(2147483647))) and
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.TYPE_NAME <> 'ENUM') order by
> INFORMATION_SCHEM A.DOMAINS.DOMAIN_SCHEMA,
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS.DOMAIN_NAME [90150-214]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632)
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
> at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.getInvalidPrecisionException(Parser.java:6325)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfDataType1(Parser.java:6285)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfDataType(Parser.java:6087)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:6069)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermWithoutIdentifier(Parser.java:5107)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4901)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3398)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:3385)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:3350)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3132)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:3053)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readInPredicate(Parser.java:3277)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readConditionRightHandSide(Parser.java:3167)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3144)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:3053)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermWithoutIdentifier(Parser.java:4990)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4901)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3398)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:3385)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:3350)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3132)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpressionWithGlobalConditions(Parser.java:3043)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2881)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2762)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2633)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2612)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2605)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2598)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2567)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
> at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
> at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
> at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
> at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
> at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
> at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
> at org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(ProviderEnabledConnection.java:109)
> at org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(SettingsEnabledConnection.java:73)
> at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.prepare(AbstractResultQuery.java:262)
> at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:342)
> ... 15 more

But it i don't have the problem with the 2.6.0 spring boot version.

Does anyone has an idea?
Thank's!

Comment: the H2 hibernate driver allows only a field length of at most `1000000000`, but `2147483647` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, if possible you can just use a different database (like SQLIte or postgreSQL), this should only affect your unit tests I assume because I see postgre in your dependencies.

Comment: How can i do that? because it is used internally i think

Comment: Can't help you there I'm afraid, it's probably connected to "jooq", but I don't know that framework, you can also try managing an older H2 driver version as that change was introduced fairly recently (a year or two ago or so), probably the spring version increase brought the newer h2 dependency version